# FLASH AS3 Sound Overlap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

Alright, I'm a total noob in flash as3 so this must be very easy to solve I guess. I'm making a soundboard with recorded voices in flash cs6, very simple: 1 frame, ten buttons, each button makes a different sound. The problem is the overlapping of these sounds, so what I need is that when I press one button the other sounds stop playing. anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

See the [`play()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play%28%29) method documentation in the [`Sound`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) class, it returns a [`SoundChannel`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html) object, which has a [`stop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html#stop%28%29) method.

So you could do it like that (schematically) :

```
var currentChannel:SoundChannel;

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    /* provided you have implemented selectSoundByButton func somewhere */

    const sound:Sound = selectSoundByButton(event.currentTarget);

    if (currentChannel) {
        currentChannel.stop();
    }

    currentChannel = sound.play();
}
```

More detailed description:

Let's say you want to create yet another fart button application in flash. That's what you have to do:

1. Create a button symbol, add it to stage and give it an instance name in properties tab. Let's call it myButton
2. Add the sound to library with file->import
3. Export this sound to actionscript. Right click on a sound in library, check "Export for actionscript", "export in frame 1" on "actionscript tab". Fill "Class" input with a desired class name for a sound (e.g. MySound)
4. Then you have to trigger the sound playback on your button click. So you should put the following code to the first frame of your flash clip:

   ```
   import flash.media.Sound;
   import flash.media.SoundChannel;
   import flash.events.MouseEvent;

   var currentChannel:SoundChannel;
   const mySound:Sound = new MySound();

   function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {    
       if (currentChannel) {
           currentChannel.stop();
       }
       currentChannel = mySound.play();
   }

   myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
   ```

Comment: hey man thank you for your answer. i really don't know what you mean, so let's say there's only one button. can you tell me what to do so everytime i hit the button the sound starts over but without overlapping, where exactly do i put this code.

Comment: i followed the steps but to no avail. the button is now called "myButton" and the class for the sound (with name "goodmorning") is called "MySound" as you suggested, so i could paste the code without any changes, but doesn't work yet. everytime i click the button a new sound comes. tell me, is it easier in AS2? maybe i could start over. i appreciate your help brother.

Comment: Well it should start over each time you click the button, stopping the previous playback. Isn't that what you wanted? Maybe you should try to create fresh project and follow these steps again ('cause i don't know what you've already done in your existing project). AS2 would probably be equally problematic for you, because you don't really know the foundations.

Comment: Don't fall back to AS2.

Comment: just want to thank you both for your support, but i found a much simpler solution using as2. all i needed was this code: onMouseDown = function () {
 stopAllSounds();
}; set it in the actions of the first and only frame of the timeline, and that's it. anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your code on each button before playing a sound:

```
SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

If you're adding actions directly from the timeline in Adobe Flash, there's no need to import the class. If you're working from an IDE like *FlashDevelop* or *FlashBuilder*, add this code to the beginning (after `Package {`):

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
```

Happy coding!

Edit: [More info on the SoundMixer class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html)

Comment: it solve the PO question but by offering potentially another problem. Voted down. SoundMixer.stopAll(); will stop any sound currently playing and not just the ones mentioned in the question. What if PO later on needs a background music? Or if other sounds are supposed to play somewhere else? The solution offered here will create more problem than it has solved.

Comment: It's not a bad function to know. I'd have suggested something more in depth than this (like storing button sounds to a variable and stopping the current sound before playing the next one).

However, the OP posted that they were a noob and I doubt they're adding background music. This is a quick fix for someone who doesn't know or want to code.